# EF Core, workaround for group by first/firstordefault?

Tags: c#, .net-core, group-by, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core

periodQuery contain **date**, **property key**, **property value** and **extra info**.
The extra info is same on all combinations of property key and value except when the date is different.

I want to get the first "extra info" for each date because they are same. In EF 6 I could use group by but not in EF Core.

I cannot execute the code client-side because I get a memory overflow exception.

I tried this the date groups give me 30 dates if I filter for 1 month.

However I get duplicated results and not all dates with `2017-01-05` are shown multiple times.

datesEx is later executed using batch/pagination.

```
var dateGroups = periodQuery.Select(x => x.Date).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x.Date); //working

var datesEx = dateGroups.Select(g => periodQuery.Where(x => g.Date == x.Date).FirstOrDefault()); //not working
```

Comment: What is `periodQuery`? Anyway, you;re using it in a circular way. That's asking for trouble. (Remember that the first statement is executed in the the second statement)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it was related to the bad database design as date is a nchar10. I cannot change the underlying tables.

First I did use `HasConversion` during entity configuration, later I traded creating a view with cast to `datetime` but it gave same results.

So did I do something wrong or is it some kind of `EF Core` bug?

Instead I created a new view with the desired query.